# How do I make the bot react to its own message? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make the bot react to its own voting message so like if theres 5 reactions, 60 second timeout, 10 reactions, 2 minutes, etc. I cant do it for about 4 hours of research. what do i do??

Here my current code with no reaction system.

```
@bot.tree.command(name = 'timeout_vote', description = 'vote for someone to be timed out')
@app_commands.checks.has_any_role('verified')
@app_commands.describe(timeout = 'Person you want to vote on to timeout')
async def timeout_vote(interaction: discord.Interaction, timeout: discord.Member, reason: str = 'No reason given'):
  embed = discord.Embed(title = 'TIMEOUT VOTE', description = '')
  embed.set_author(name = timeout.name, icon_url = timeout.display_avatar)
  embed.add_field(name = 'Member being voted on:', value = timeout.mention, inline = True)
  embed.add_field(name = 'Responsible vote executer:', value = interaction.user.mention, inline = True)
  if timeout.display_avatar == None:
    embed.set_image(url = interaction.avatar.url)
  else:
    embed.set_image(url = timeout.display_avatar)
  vote = '\N{WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK}'
  await interaction.response.send_message(embed = embed)

@timeout_vote.error
async def timeout_vote_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, app_commands.MissingAnyRole):
    await bot.get_channel(1106325554942197992).send(content = 'You must be verified to complete this command')
```

Comment: how long do you want the bot to keep reacting to the command (for how many times)? Do you want the bot to also add reactions to its own message like users or do you want to change the original message? Why do you need reactions to this command?

Comment: @TimG233 So basically i own a small server with my school and i want people to place votes for someone to be timedout. i probably want this reaction for 1 minute?